# Javascript autocomplete works in IE and Chrome, doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, autocomplete

I'm working on a client's site which utilizes a Javascript autocomplete feature in the search form. The website is in Hebrew, but please don't let that scare you away - my issue is in code, not English. :) 
Link: -removed by author-
Most of the autocompletion options are in Hebrew but I added "test" so that it will be easy to test in English as well. 
Basically this autocomplete script generates a text input box, and when the user types in a letter (`onkeyup`), a list of common values are offered (e.g. "test").
This works fine in both Chrome and IE, but for some reason Firefox is behaving differently.
When you enter a letter in Firefox, according to the error console:

```
Error: searchResult1 is not defined
Source File: 
Line: 1
```

Same goes for `searchResult0` in the second input field (line ~460 in the source code). 
If you look at -removed- the autocomplete script *does* work in Firefox, so I don't really know what it is I could have changed that broke its functionality. 
Thank you for any help with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `onkeyup="searchResult1.style.visibility='visible';..."`, it should be `document.getElementById('searchResult1').style.visibility` - you are referring to an element by its ID. It's an old MSIE feature that elements with an ID turn into "global variables" but that's really not something you should use. Other browsers implemented support for this misfeature ("global scope pollution") to stay compatible with MSIE but it is merely a compatibility layer and only kicks in under certain conditions.

Comment: you just saved my ass - I bow down to you.
The script actually isn't mine, it was implemented by someone who was working on the site before me, and really did a great job of messing it up. I had to keep all of the current scripts as part of the job, and that included this autocomplete script. 
I appreciate the tips on ditching this specific script, but as I mentioned I will have to keep it in this particular case due to my client's wishes.
Anyway - thanks again, this has been driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using jquery autocomplete plugin rather than writing something on your own. The javascript written is not proper.

Its best to use the jquery autocomplete plugin. I see in you code you are jquery1.5.2

Autocomplete Demo:
http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/

Download and documentation
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: My client has requested that I keep all original scripts (this one wasn't written by myself), and for that reason alone I can't use any "outside" scripts - but I will take this into consideration in future. Thank you!